# Transform appsettings.json file in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to transform the appsettings.json file for my Dotnet 3.0 test project, via the Jenkins Pipeline.
The jenkins pipeline (depending on agent), will pass a specific IP address which I want to change in the settings file so that when the application is build and deployed it uses the new IP address.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'SERVER_ADDRESS', defaultValue: '127.0.0.1', description: 'IP Address of Server');
  }
  stages {
    stage('Change Appsettings') {
      steps {
        echo "Address is ${params.SERVER_ADDRESS}"
        sed -i '/ServerGateway/c\ \"ServerGateway\": \"'+${params.SERVER_ADDRESS}+'\",' TestWebapi/appsettings.json
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
       "ServerGateway": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

I really don't know whats the better way of doing this, maybe there is a plugin, but all i know is i can use sed.

Any better and cleaner solution is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to read the value of `ServerGateway` from appSettings.json in your Jenkinsfile?

Comment: No, i want to change the value in appsettings.json file based on the passed parameter

Comment: Okay, why cant you just save it to a variable and use the variable?

Comment: What do you mean? save it to which variable and how will that variable be saved in the file?

Comment: @Aeseir In .NET Core you don't *transform* files, you override some settings by using another settings provider or file. The default generic host loads `appsettings.json` and then `appsettings.Environment.json`, where `Environment` can be Development, Production etc. You can load your own settings from environment varialbes, other files, databases etc

Answer (score 1):

As I've understood your question - you want to modify the value of ServerGateway 
 in **AppSettings.json**. You can do this like this.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def json = new JsonSlurper()
appSettings = json.parse(new File("path_to_AppSettings.json"))
```

then assign the new value you want to use

```
appSettings['ConnectionStrings'].ServerGateway = Your New Value
println(appSettings['ConnectionStrings'].ServerGateway) // will have your new value stored.
```

---

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def cfg = ""


def storeNewValue(serverAdress) {
    def json = new JsonSlurper()
    appSettings = json.parse(new File("TestWebapi/appsettings.json"))
    appSettings['ConnectionStrings'].ServerGateway = serverAdress
    cfg = appSettings
    //return appSettings['ConnectionStrings'].ServerGateway
}

pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'SERVER_ADDRESS', defaultValue: '127.0.0.1', description: 'IP Address of Server');
  }
  stages {
    stage('Change Appsettings') {
      steps {
        echo "Address is ${params.SERVER_ADDRESS}"
        storeNewValue(params.SERVER_ADDRESS)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After this you can access the new values with `cfg`

Comment: So how will that look like in context of the pipeline?

Comment: @aeseir See update. *Assuming SERVER_ADDRESS is what you want to pass*

Comment: so this combination will change the file appsettings.json, and not just display the value of cfg?

Comment: correct, as long as this process is running, appsettings.json will have its values modified. Until `storeNewValue` is called, it will have the old values. dislaimer: i typed this on my phone, so you might have to tinker a bit with the solution, but the concept is there :)

Comment: Its failing unfortunately, cannot find the file. Is it possible its trying to parse file before pipeline has had chance to checkout the code?

Comment: well, i dont know how your filestructure is setup. that you have to figure out on your own. :) try `./path_to_file` (if it is in the same dir)

Comment: TestWebapi is the folder and inside it is the appsettings.json. If the new File is running from directory that Jenkinsfile is located in then should be working, unless its triggered from another location

Comment: check what your directory is at execution, `def myAbsDir = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile().getParent()

println(myAbsDir)`

or just echo it out.

however, this is not part of the question and this is up to you and your environment to figure out - I cannot help with that.

Comment: Still investigating, something is going on with JsonSlurper, i've determined its in right location but JsonSlurper is not cooperating with new File.

Comment: upper/lowercase problems? And dont forget to actually install jsonslurper.

Comment: i've just done about 10 different combinations, including that. Its done my head in, coz without slurper it works, but the minute it hits the json.parse it blows up.

Comment: *And dont forget to actually install jsonslurper*

Answer (score 0):

Use Environment Variables.

Environment variables override the configuration values specified in `appsettings.json`, and are the best way to configure your settings on a CI environment like Jenkins. They do if you're using the `CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` or if you're using `Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables` which you're probably using.

In your current case you're trying to override the following setting:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "ServerGateway": "127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

You can do that by setting the following environmental variable: `ConnectionStrings:ServerGateway=connectionstring...` if your environment does not support colons (:) you can substitute them with a double underscore like `ConnectionStrings__ServerGateway=connectionstring...`.

You can get more info on this approach [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-3.0#simple-configuration)

Comment: I've considered this, however next phase is to containerise, and you don't want env variables in containers, especially if you use orchestration service

Comment: Yes you do! That’s what I do all the time with my kubernettes. In fact the hint about the “__” instead of : its because kubernettes does not support : in a env variable name.

Comment: Sorry to clarify, connection string i want to avoid storing in env variables. I will be leveraging service mesh for this part. This is first of many connection strings i want to eventually transition out of config altogether.